# JHipster cannot login after starting with yarn start (webpack)

Tags: webpack, jhipster

I cannot login with default admin or test into the generated **JHipster (4.2.0)** monolithic app (maven, mysql on dev&prod, ES, Angular4 with i18n - no proxy set) after starting it with **"yarn start"** (works with **"./mvnw"** though).

**Console log:**

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/profile-info from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
>       [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/account from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
>       [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/profile-info from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
>       [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/authentication from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
>       [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/logout from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Before start I ran a maven test with the wrapper and started the mysql & elasticsearch docker containers (generated in *src/main/docker*).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have noticed that the database got initialised only when I started the app with **"./mvnw"**, the previous attempt starting with **"yarn start"** did not trigger the _liquidbase_ to initialise the database. Is this normal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error means that browsersync/webpack could not connect to the java backend on port 8080 for proxying API calls: the spring boot application must be running. You must run both "./mvnw" and "yarn start". See [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/using-angular/) and webpack/webpack.dev.js file

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not have trouble on a second machine (also macOS Sierra) logging-in, I generated same monolithic app and I am unable to login (neither with webpack or wihtout, also tried the docker containers deployment and still failure to login). The only log I get is the "rejected access" entry so I am not sure that the difference may be as on the other machine it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: I have found the problem mentioned above and wanted to mention it here, if anyone would encounter the same issue. The problem was a cookie for XSRF token which was created by a different app (locally), clearing the cookies fixed them issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also force maven/gradle to run the `webpack:dev` task while starting by passing the webpack profile like `./mvnw -Pdev,webpack` or `./gradlew -Pdev -Pwebpack`. This is especially helpful after running a clean task.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, it was because I had changed my service port, to 8081.
If that's the case, you should set the port to the changed one in the file;

> webpack/webpack.dev.js

```
proxy: [{
        context: [
            .....
        ],
        target: `http${options.tls ? 's' : ''}://localhost:8081`,
```